# Replace & with "and" in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I am trying to work on an XSLT where I want to replace all occurrences of special character `&` with `and` in XML. One of the few things I have tried

```
<xsl:element name="ext_udf_str1">
<xsl:value-of select="replace(/*:SyncCLShipment/*:DataArea/*:CLShipment/*:Shipment/*:ShipmentHeader/*:PickMsgLine1,'&amp;','and')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `replace()` *should* work, but there's no way to know why it doesn't because you haven't given a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

However, if you're using `replace()` you're using at least XSLT 2.0 so using a [character map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-character-map) is another option.

Example (This is XSLT 3.0. It works in 2.0 if you replace the `xsl:mode` with the identity transform template.):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="so"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:character-map name="so">
        <xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="and"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyho7z/2

Comment: Updated to remove `expand-text` which makes it easier to convert to 2.0 if needed.